# Rails: How to set default timezone to a specific one for the whole application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, timezone

How do I set default timezone for Rails and ActiveRecord? I have a lot of places where time is diplayed(for example creation of some instance in the database, etc.). The time is displayed in my current timezone. Should i somehow configure Rails/ActiveRecord or *nix distributive that i am using on hosting platform?

I've tryied to add that to `application.rb` file without any result:

```
config.time_zone = 'Moscow'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

I've also tried to use

```
config.time_zone = 'Moscow'
config.active_record.default_timezone = "Moscow"
```

But in that case i get a warning

```
warning: :database_timezone option must be :utc or :local - defaulting to :local
```

Is there a solution that will prevent me from changing all those places where time is rendered?

Comment: Not sure what your intended outcome is. Surely displaying all times translated into the local timezone of the user viewing the page is desirable? Active record stores times as UTC and only translates them on the way out again, so showing them in Moscow time when the user is in London would be confusing.

Comment: @Matt Gibson
But that is what i'm intending to do. I mean showing them in Moscow time when the user is in London would be confusing

Comment: So you mean that the normal local setting is not working and you are getting UTC (or Moscow if that's what it's set to) times all over the place?

Answer (score 1):

Just try using the below given one only in **application.rb**,

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

discard,

```
config.time_zone
```

May that help you.

Answer (score 0):

First off: I'm always for not messing with the way AR stores time stamps, because Rails already does all the magic about time conversion for you.

I assume you want to display the times in your app in the time zone the current user has selected (or that you have determined per-user in some other way). In that case what you configured in `config.time_zone` is of no consequence, because you obviously want to overwrite it. Rails has a neat mechanism for this called [`Time.use_zone`](http://apidock.com/rails/Time/use_zone/class).

I used that in an `around_filter` before, like this:

```
around_filter :set_time_zone

def set_time_zone
  Time.use_zone(current_user.try(:time_zone) || Time.zone) do
    yield
  end
end
```

This sets the time zone for the current request to the current_user's time_zone if that user is present. Falls back to the time zone configured in application.rb otherwise.

Inside the [`Time.use_zone`](http://apidock.com/rails/Time/use_zone/class) block, all times are displayed and saved as in that zone.

What's very handy about this approach is that after each request the time zone is reset to what is configured. If you'd just change Time.zone and wouldn't bother resetting it, it can potentially leak to other users.

I suggest you try this and see if it does what you want before trying to wrap your head around what all this means, because that can make your head spin. I'm happy to explain more about the how and why, if you're interested, though.